# Filtering a Cross Tab by a Date Range in Crystal Reporting

Tags: crystal-reports

I've got a cross tab that sums the number of records for each month across my data set, however I don't want all of the data set. I only want the cross tab to sum the data for each of the months for records that are related to the dates between 01/01/2022 to 31/12/2022.

Normally I would set a filter on the report to say this, but I am adding another section to the report which would not work if I had that filter set. I only want the filter to apply to the actual cross tab information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hiya, its not so much about coding. I've got a field which has a range of dates from 2018 to 2025, however I only want the cross tab to look at records which fall between 01/01/2022 - 31/12/2022

Comment: It might be possible in a subreport if nobody has any other ideas.  The subreport could filter the data set so the crosstab doesn't need to, and the main report would continue to use the unfiltered data set.

Comment: Would I be able to combine both the main report and the sub report if I did that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you ask if this would allow you to combine the main report and subreport.  Could you elaborate please?